# Pass hashed password to Java Mail API

Tags: java, email, imap, jakarta-mail

Good morning everybody,

I'm developping an ERP for my company with the GWT Framework and I would get
the number of unread emails using the Java Mail API.
I can do this but, the problem is I stores the SHA-512 hashed password on the
database and I would not pass the clear password to the Java Mail API, but just the hashed password to avoiding to transmit the clear password on the network.

I use this code to get the number of unread mail:

```
private static int getNumberOfUnreadMails() {
   int numberOfUnreadMails = 0;

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", "myserver.com");
    properties.put("mail.imap.user", "developper@myserver.com");
    properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory", 143);
    properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "java.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", 143);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("developper@myserver.com", "mypassword");
        }
    });
    Store store;
    try {
        store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect();
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
           numberOfUnreadMails = folder.getUnreadMessageCount();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numberOfUnreadMails;
}
```

I can also use another hashing algorithm.
If you know a solution for my problem, thaks you in advance.

P.S.: Sorry for my poor English, I’m French.

Comment: Just encrypt the traffic (looks like you might be doing that already).  The password shouldn't be clear already if you're doing that.  Hashing the password client-side actually makes for a less secure system, since it defeats any purpose of a salt (unless on the server you're salting the hash and then rehashing).  If you're not using a salt, then the hash just becomes a new password that you're sending in clear text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I thought to this solution, use SSL connection between the client and the server, but if the server is compromise, the hacker can get the clear password.

Comment: What you don't see is that if you could send the hash then the hash IS the clear password for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your IMAP-server will need the unhashed password to be able to authenticate. You probably are already using SSL (as you set `mail.imap.socketFactory.class`), so your password is never sent in the clear.

BTW: the correct way to use IMAP with SSL with javamail is to use the `imaps` protocol (and use the `mail.imaps.*`, not using the imap protocol and specifying an SSL socket factory as the socket factory. Also usually the IMAP with SSL port is 993, not 143 .

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I will correct this. Is there a way to use a hashed password on the server like the CRAM-MD5 systems and send it to the server via the JavaMail API ?

Comment: IMAP has several authentication option (support depends on the server), and Javamail supports various authentication option (using sasl). I haven't used Javamail in a while, so I can't easily tell what you exactly need to do to get that working.