# What and how should i use to send error logs from my java program onto a server (mail, git, etc...)

Tags: java, git, email, server

I have an alpha staged program with many bugs, and I would like to let people send their logs on a server (mail, git, etc...) so i can look them up and fix them. I have searched allot on this topic and I haven't found a way to do it without downloading a git full of logs, or needing an authentication for a mail or a dedicated server.

Is there a way to make my Java program send automatically its error log on a server when it crashes, without needing costly hardware or authentification? (i have a 0$ budget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/) account sounds perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `javamail` [library](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to send emails to an account where you want to get the errorlogs. This wouldn't cost anything. And is very fast to implement/integrate in your project.

I would suggest to create a new gmail account which will send the emails to your account, where you want to recieve and debug it.

Comment: is there a way to obfuscate the password so it cannot be found in the bytecode?

Comment: According to http://oracle.developer-works.com/article/5443481/reading+mail+with+password+hash it is possible to send just the passwort hash, if your mail-server is able to understand it. And this SO-Post says basically the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673989/pass-hashed-password-to-java-mail-api . But I myself haven't tried it up to know...